# How to access caller object's members via called method in JAVA

Tags: java

Here is my code

```
class Base
{
  public void fillRandomData()
  {
    //code for accessing members for sub classes
        //here object "b" is calling this method
        //I want to access members of caller object
        //As it is Derived class how can I access its member 
  }
}

class Derived extends Base
{
  Map<String, List<Integer>> fields = new HashMap<String,List<Integer>>();
  List<Integer> attribute = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Derived() {
        attribute.add(1);
        fields.put("textbox",attribute);
    }
}

class Main
{
     public static void main(String[] argv) {
         Base b = new Base();
       **b.fillRandomData();**
     }
}
```

The above code explains my question.
I am stucked in accessing caller object members 
I think retrospection will help But it doesn't helped me alot.

As in ruby there is method "instance_variable_get(instance_var)" which allows to access data members of caller object.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean with caller object members. the code above does not compile. Perhaps you can describe in more detail what you actually are trying to do? or perhaps post the actual code you are writing, rather than the pseudocode?

Comment: Ah ok you want to access members of the Derived part of the instance, from code in the Base part? that is not recommended practice. There are ways around this though.

Comment: @Joeblade caller object's member means the object which is calling the method.
Here in this case  _b.fillRandomData()_ "b" is the object And I want to access members of "b" in "fillRandomData()" in this method.

Comment: And @override will not help If I have n no. of sub classes which is extending "Base" class will increase LOC as well as maintainability   of code
As I wanted "fillRandomData()" method's definition written at single place I has access to it's child classes's members.

Comment: I am reading this as: I want to access elements of Derived from Base. This is bad practice. It will embed information about your subclasses (their structure) in your parent class. This means your parent class will have to be updated whenever you add a subclass. Not everyone will have access to the parent class (for instance if it lives in another jar file) so not everyone can do this. If you really must, then reflection is the way you can do it, but I believe you'll end up painting yourself into a corner. For this reason I won't list it as an answer. look at delegation for your real solution.

Answer (score 1):

you must defined method and call your method into you can't call method in class block.

like this :

```
class Main
{
void callMethod(){
  Base b = new Base ();
  b.fillRandomData();
}
}
```

Comment: This is essentially the code sample from the question - don't see this makes a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

from what I understand from your question you want to do something like:

```
class Base
{
  public void fillRandomData()
  {
      // do not directly access members. you can use reflect to do this but do not do this.
      // (unless you have a real reason for it)
      //
      // instead, trust on the subclasses to correctly override fillRandomData to fill in the
  }
}

class Derived extends Base
{
    Map<String, List<Integer>> fields = new HashMap<String,List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> attribute = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Derived() {
        attribute.add(1);
        fields.put("textbox",attribute);
    }

    @Override
    public void fillRandomData() {
         // in Main, the b.fillRandomData will run this method.

         // let the Base class set it's part of the data
         super.fillRandomData();

         // then let this class set it's data
         // do stuff with attributes
         // do stuff with fields.
    }
 }

class Main
{
  // you _must_ instantiate a derived object if you want to have a chance at getting it's instance variables
    public static void main(String[] argv) { 
        Base b = new Derived();
        b.fillRandomData();
    }
}
```

Comment: For completeness and educational purpose, the overriden method should have an `@override` annotation

Comment: Good point. I'm a bad coder and hardly ever use those, my editor fixes that sort of thing for me. so writing code manually makes me forget.